# Python mock class variable which is an object

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a two classes, like this:

```py
class A:
    def someFunction(self):
        print("does work")

class B:
    def __init__():
        self.instance_a = A()
```

I want to mock `A.someFunction()` in a unit test. How do I mock the class variable, `self.instance_a`?

Comment: `self.instance_a = A()` directly in the class? You'd get an error for that, is your question related to that or is that a typo while posting your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock just the method inside the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407741/how-to-mock-just-the-method-inside-the-class)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat sorry, you're right. It should be inside `__init__():`

Comment: I don't think the linked thread here answers my question, no. I am trying to mock the use of `self.instance_a` in class B. I wish to mock the entire class and all of it's functions.

Comment: Are you asking this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39004540/mock-entire-python-class

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your production code is contained in the following file `prod.py`:

```
class A:
    def someFunction(self):
        print("does work")

class B:
    def __init__(self):   # <--- here in your code you miss the self argument
        self.instance_a = A()
```

A possible test code which mocks the method `someFunction()` of the class `A` is the following:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from prod import B

# this function is used for mocking the method someFunction()
def someFunction_mocked():
    print('some function mocked')

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    # the following method uses the production code
    def test_something(self):
        sut = B()
        sut.instance_a.someFunction()

    # the following method substitute the object points by instance_a by a Mock object
    def test_something_2(self):
        sut = B()
        with mock.patch.object(sut, 'instance_a') as mock_a:
            mock_a.someFunction.side_effect = someFunction_mocked
            sut.instance_a.someFunction()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The test code is saved in the same folder of the file `prod.py`. The function `someFunction()` is substituted by the function `someFunction_mocked()` which prints the message `some function mocked` instead the message `does work`.

The output of the execution of the test  code  is:

```
does work
some function mocked
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

where the output is produces as following:

- the message `does work` is printed by the test method `test_something()`
- the message `some function mocked` is printed by the test method `test_something_2()`. In this second method is present the instruction `mock.patch.object()` which performs the mocking.